# (Go Generics) IncompatibleAssign & MismatchedTypes error - Why am I receiving this error?

Tags: go, generics, types

I am exploring generics (ignore the fact that using generics here doesn't make sense, I am aware of it) and I just got an error that does make much sense for me (I mainly use Typescript and this would be a valid case).

Isn't T int? So why can't I use it in my for-loop or waitGroup, for example?

**Error in waitGroup:** *var length T - cannot use length (variable of type T constrained by int) as int value in argument to waitGroup.Add | Compiler - (IncompatibleAssign)*

**Error in for-loop:** *var i int - invalid operation: cannot compare i < length (mismatched types int and T) | Compiler - (MismatchedTypes)*

```
// Dummy code :)
func CreateUserList[T int](length T) []*User {
    users := make([]*User, length)

    waitGroup := sync.WaitGroup{}
    waitGroup.Add(length)

    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            users[i] = newUser()
            waitGroup.Done()
        }(i)
    }

    waitGroup.Wait()

    return users
}
```

Comment: `T` is not `int`, it's just *constrained* by it. You have to convert. `waitGroup.Add(int(length))`

Comment: @blackgreen But "make" accepts T and make accepts only "Int" in theory. The for-loop accepts an Int as well, but it doesn't accept T. It does not much sense for me.

Comment: `make`is a language builtin, and its [signature](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#make) accepts an `IntegerType`, which is a special type for any integer. So it accepts `T`. The for loop is using `length` only with an order operator `<`, which is supported by the constraint.